# ArrayList method in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I tried to create arrayList method in JSP as the following :

```
    <%!
       public int x = 0;
       public ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
       array.add(new ArrayList());
       public ArrayList cidTime (int cid, int w)
       {
            ((ArrayList)array.get(x)).add(cid);
            ((ArrayList)array.get(x)).add(w);
            x++;
            return array;
       }
      %>
```

but it returned error :

```
                    Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) 
                    Syntax error on token "add", = expected after this token
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Don't put Java code in your JSP pages, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/249327 for many reasons why. Do that in your controller or else create a taglib and put the code there.

Comment: Also, you have asked 8 questions on SO but have not accepted any answers for them (click the tick icon under the vote number on the right side of the answer) - people won't bother answering your questions if you continue this trend.

Comment: Learn basic Java first before switching to JSP. This ain't JSP problem

Comment: @nickdos: ok, thanks. I will follow your suggestion. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JSP declaration tag `<%!`. According to the info [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-declaration-tag) it places **declarations and methods** outside the `service` method body of the JSP page. Which means that your call `array.add(new ArrayList());` is causing the problem because it is not variable declaration or method declaration.